# error occurs when starting mysql group replication

Tags: mysql, replication

With MySQL 8.0.15, I tried to set up the group replication according to the manual(not all the same steps), but the errors occurred. Maybe I missed some details.

I was trying to set up the first node. After I execute START Group_replication, MySQL returned `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query` .

The log:

```
2019-06-17T21:06:43.310572Z 2 [Note] [MY-011671] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Group communication SSL configuration: group_replication_ssl_mode: "REQUIRED"; server_key_file: "server-key.pem"; server_cert_file: "server-cert.pem"; client_key_file: "server-key.pem"; client_cert_file: "server-cert.pem"; ca_file: "ca.pem"; ca_path: ""; cipher: ""; tls_version: "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"; crl_file: ""; crl_path: ""; ssl_fips_mode: "OFF"'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.312218Z 2 [Note] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Debug messages will be sent to: asynchronous::/var/lib/mysql/GCS_DEBUG_TRACE'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.316231Z 2 [Note] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Translated 'ic-1' to 192.168.1.3'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.316261Z 2 [Note] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Translated 'ic-1' to 192.168.1.3'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.316267Z 2 [Note] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Translated 'ic-1' to 192.168.1.3'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.316945Z 2 [Warning] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Automatically adding IPv4 localhost address to the whitelist. It is mandatory that it is added.'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.316967Z 2 [Warning] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Automatically adding IPv6 localhost address to the whitelist. It is mandatory that it is added.'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.386253Z 2 [Note] [MY-011694] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Initialized group communication with configuration: group_replication_group_name: '535d9684-8d27-11e9-ac7d-000c2992d1b0'; group_replication_local_address: 'ic-1:33061'; group_replication_group_seeds: '192.168.1.3:33061,192.168.1.2:33061,192.168.1.6:33061'; group_replication_bootstrap_group: 'true'; group_replication_poll_spin_loops: 0; group_replication_compression_threshold: 1000000; group_replication_ip_whitelist: '192.168.1.3,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.6'; group_replication_communication_debug_options: 'GCS_DEBUG_NONE'; group_replication_member_expel_timeout: '0''
2019-06-17T21:06:43.393819Z 2 [Note] [MY-011643] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Member configuration: member_id: 1; member_uuid: "48b18276-416d-11e9-8af6-000c2992d1b0"; single-primary mode: "true"; group_replication_auto_increment_increment: 7; '
2019-06-17T21:06:43.398801Z 0 [Note] [MY-011240] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Using SSL configuration from MySQL Server'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.402775Z 10 [System] [MY-010597] [Repl] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_applier' executed'. Previous state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2019-06-17T21:06:43.403738Z 0 [Note] [MY-011243] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Using OpenSSL for TLS connections'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.403738Z 0 [Note] [MY-011243] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Using OpenSSL for TLS connections'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.404025Z 0 [Note] [MY-011323] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'X Plugin ready for connections. bind-address: '::' port: 33060'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.404043Z 0 [Note] [MY-011323] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'X Plugin ready for connections. socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock''
2019-06-17T21:06:43.413207Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2019-06-17T21:06:43.427685Z 13 [Note] [MY-010581] [Repl] Slave SQL thread for channel 'group_replication_applier' initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log './ic-1-relay-bin-group_replication_applier.000001' position: 4
2019-06-17T21:06:43.428136Z 2 [Note] [MY-011670] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Group Replication applier module successfully initialized!'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.469690Z 0 [Note] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] XCom protocol version: 6'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.469724Z 0 [Note] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] XCom initialized and ready to accept incoming connections on port 33061'
2019-06-17T21:06:43.469938Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error connecting to the local group communication engine instance.'
2019-06-17T21:06:44.498775Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member was unable to join the group. Local port: 33061'
2019-06-17T21:07:43.428353Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-011640] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Timeout on wait for view after joining group'
2019-06-17T21:07:43.448195Z 2 [Note] [MY-011649] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Requesting to leave the group despite of not being a member'
2019-06-17T21:07:43.454619Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member is leaving a group without being on one.'
2019-06-17T21:07:43.498575Z 13 [Note] [MY-010596] [Repl] Error reading relay log event for channel 'group_replication_applier': slave SQL thread was killed
2019-06-17T21:07:43.523292Z 13 [Note] [MY-010587] [Repl] Slave SQL thread for channel 'group_replication_applier' exiting, replication stopped in log 'FIRST' at position 0
2019-06-17T21:07:43.572362Z 10 [Note] [MY-011444] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'The group replication applier thread was killed.'
```

In fact, I don’t think the log provided information that was useful enough.

Hope get some useful information here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12790569/1374644) ?

Comment: I did not try it, but the main problem is that the group replication cannot be started successfully. It looks like the connection problem was caused by the replication problem.